# Find the running time of an algorithm

Tags: performance, iteration, time-complexity, formula

I was watching a youtube video on Time Complexity Analysis of Iterative Programs: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FEnwM-iDb2g

And I cannot figure out how he calculated what's happening to line 5. 
The answer is k(k+1)/2.
Just wondering is there certain steps I can follow or ways of thinking to figure this formula out. I know that s is the sum of the previous numbers of i. For example, i = 1, 2. Then s = 3. Or if i= 1, 2, 3, then s= 6.

But I just don't know how to make up a formula for this on my own.

```
A(){  
i=1;          //1
s=1;          //2
while(s<=n){  //3 Value of n could be any positive integer.
  i++;        //4
  s=s+i;      //5
  print("hello");  //6
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the value of n?

Comment: It could be anything. 1, 2, 3, etc.

Comment: This is directly implied from the [formula for the partial integer sum `1 + 2 + 3 ... + N`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is: When is the `while` loop going to terminate. Say it will terminate at the `k`th iteration. That is, when `i=k` it will terminate. As you said, s is the summation of all `i`s the iteration has encountered. That is, when `i=k`, s equals `1+2+...+k`. This sum is equal to `k(k+1)/2`.

After this step one needs to link this quantity to `n` and express `k` in terms of `n` to get the final complexity.

Does that answer your question? Please comment at which step you want more details.

P.S. Here is a really cool animated proof of the arithmetic progression summation: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Animated_proof_for_the_formula_giving_the_sum_of_the_first_integers_1%2B2%2B...%2Bn.gif